# embeddedforms and the event dispatcher

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have 3 forms, one is a `SalesForm`, `SalesItemForm` and `EmbedSalesItemForm`

I have the `SalesItemForm` into my `SalesForm` using `embedRelation('SalesItems', EmbedSalesItemForm)`

These work well and when I view the sale, I see the items embedded into it. That is fine.

What I'm looking to do though, is to check if a value appears in any of the embedded forms values and if so, possibly hook into an event dispatcher/listener in order to send an email.

I can get the forms values via:

```
public function processValues($values) {

    var_dump($values);exit;

    return parent::processValues($values);

}
```

This returns:

```
    array
      'SalesItems' => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              'id' => string '38' (length=2)
              'quantity' => int 1
              'sku' => string 'test1' (length=9)
              'description' => string 'test1' (length=5)
              'price' => float 9.99
              'out_of_stock' => null
          1 => 
            array
              'id' => string '39' (length=2)
              'out_of_stock' => string 'on' (length=2)
              'quantity' => int 1
              'sku' => string '1234' (length=4)
              'description' => string 'test' (length=4)
              'price' => float 9.99
      'id' => string '20' (length=2)
      'first_name' => string 'Test' (length=4)
      'last_name' => string 'Name' (length=4)
      'email_address' => string 'test@test.com' (length=13)
```

Ideally, I need to check whether or not the `out_of_stock` is `on`. This is a checkbox field

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need something like this:

```
public function processValues($values) {

    if(isset($values)){
      foreach($values as $value){
        if($value['out_of_stock'] == 'on'){ // The checkbox is checked
          // Send mail
        }
      }
    }

    return parent::processValues($values);

}
```